# Проблема с запуском игры на Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Дело в том что настройки игры, а именно момент когда я хочу сохранить значения PlayerPrefs, и в тестировочном режиме запустить свои наработки, происходит непонятная вещь. Дело в том что Unity не сохраняет значения по какой-то непонятной мне причине.
Например:
Допустим играю, ставлю рекорд, рекорд отображается корректно записывается в топ рекорд, но при перезапуске игры или же когда нажимаю Replay в самой запущенной игре. Все сбивается становится по 0. Все coins, все что записывается в игру с помощью PlayerPrefs. Так же почему-то сбиваются все PlayerPrefs при переходе между сценами.

Возможно после того как я скомпилирую проект, то этого не будет, но не уверен точно. Возможно кто-то встречался с подобным.

Буду благодарен за любые советы и рекомендации!

Пример кода реализации Score.

```
public int ScoreINT;    
    public Text textScore;
    public Text FinalScore;
    public Text TopRecord;

    void Start()
    {
        ScoreINT = 0;        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        textScore.text = ScoreINT.ToString();

        FinalScore.text = "Score: " + ScoreINT.ToString();

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score") < ScoreINT)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", ScoreINT);             
            TopRecord.text = "Top: " + ScoreINT.ToString();
        }
        else        
            TopRecord.text = "Top: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score").ToString();



    }
```

Comment: Ваш код работы с PlayerPrefs в студию, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил пример кода Score.

Comment: Проверьте остальной Ваш код. Возможно, где то выполняется PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll(), а Вы про него забыли.

Comment: Или вы где-то в коде делаете неудачное "обнуляющее" присваивание "Score" значения 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте остальной Ваш код. Возможно, где то выполняется PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll(), а Вы про него забыли.

Answer (score 1):

Pollux, оказался прав, огромное ему спасибо. В одном из скрипте был `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll()`, про него забыл.